# Blocked (possibly sub-frame) navigation to non-allowed URL

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am unable to open the clicked url to the browser from my application.

[image].

Is there anything which i need to add.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution for this. Add these below lines to the config.xml file.

```
<access origin="http://*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="https://*" launch-external="yes" />
```

It is working for me!!

Answer (score 1):

The Answer of @Kumar works, but I needed a tweak that can be useful to those who need to call WhatsApp from Ionic. You can allow ALL (but it's very insecure) like this:

```
<access origin="*" launch-external="yes" />
```

or you can allow whatsapp:

```
<access origin="whatsapp//*" launch-external="yes" />
```

but if you beggin with "https" will not include "whatsapp"...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answers provided here didn't work for me. Below is what worked out well:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```